# Akka and Test Cases

Tags: scala, akka

I am getting a strange error:

```
class ActorSpec
  extends TestKit(ActorSystem("ActorSpec"))
    with WordSpecLike
    with Matchers
    with JsonSupport
    with MockitoSugar
    with BeforeAndAfterAll
    with ImplicitSender {
  val actorA: ActorRef = TestActorRef(ActorA.props(mockedRepo))

  val data = Data("a", "b") 

  "AactorA" should {
    "be able to fetch contents for given host and path" in {
      when(mockedRepo.getData("data")).thenReturn(Future(Seq(data)))
      val command = actorA ? GetData("data")
      val result = Await.result(command, 10.seconds)
     result should be (data)
    }

  }
}
```

I am getting exception as Data("a", "b") was not equal to Data("a","b")

Comment: is Data simply a case class Data(s1:String, s2:String)?

Comment: When invoking your mockedRepo, you are returning a Future(Seq(Data)), you need to map the result. (.mapTo[Data]). And then you should use Future.successful(Data), so that it matches.